# How can I trace a flow instance in weblogic 12c? (apart from accessing it through EM)

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

I have tried accessing a instance information through EM and it is not responding. Where does this instance info gets picked and how can we access it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a JAVA API that can be used to retrieve information from the dehydration store (SOA database). This link shows how to use the API : http://www.ateam-oracle.com/how-to-recover-initial-messages-payload-from-soa-audit-for-mediator-and-bpel-components/